# How to disable excess auto import suggestions in VS Code / TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I have an npm package that is shipped with typings, file structure is similar to the following:

`./typings/index.d.ts`:

```
export { ISomeInterface } from './something';
```

`./typings/something.d.ts`:

```
/*
  This interface is used by the package internally,
  so I can't simply remove the export.
*/
export interface ISomeOtherInterface {
  someField: number;
}

export interface ISomeInterface {
  someObject: ISomeOtherInterface;
}
```

`./package.json`:

```
"typings": "./typings/index.d.ts"
```

The problem is whenever I type something like

```
const a: ISome...
```

VS Code's IntelliSense shows me two suggestions:

```
| Auto import ISomeInterface from 'my-package'
| Auto import ISomeOtherInterface from 'my-package/typings/something'
```

What is the correct way to prevent VS Code from auto suggesting the second import?

typescript@3.2.2, VSCode@1.30.2

UPD:

library tsconfig (the one used to generate typings for the library):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "esnext",                     
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "esnext"],                             
    "jsx": "react",  
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,                           
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 
    "strictNullChecks": true,              
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,           
    "strictBindCallApply": true,           
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  
    "noImplicitThis": true,                
    "alwaysStrict": true,                  
    "noUnusedLocals": true,                
    "noImplicitReturns": true,             
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    
    "moduleResolution": "node",            
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "typings"                   
  },
  "include": [
    "src/lib/**/*.ts",
    "src/lib/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "typings",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.tsx"
  ]
}
```

project tsconfig (the one used in the project where the library is used):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "esnext",                     
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016", "esnext"],                             
    "jsx": "react",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strict": true,                           
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 
    "strictNullChecks": true,              
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,           
    "strictBindCallApply": true,           
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,              
    "noImplicitReturns": true,             
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    
    "moduleResolution": "node",            
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/@types/*", "*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share with us your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @Vincenzo sure, original post now includes both configs

Answer (score 0):

2 things I can think of.

1. In the first tsconfig, try setting outFile to index.d.ts. It should generate 1 declaration file only.
2. Try removing this from the second tsconfig

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["node_modules/@types/*", "*"]
}
```